# Web Components spec - '({ a: 1 })' - makes 'this.a possible'

Tags: javascript, web-component

In Web Components [working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-components-intro-20130606/) (section [5.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-components-intro-20130606/#methods-and-properties)) I stumbled upon this construct:

```
<element name="tick-tock-clock">
  <script>
    ({
      tick: function () {
        …
      }
    });
  </script>
</element>
```

When used this way, I can refer to `tick` via `this` (`this.tick`) - at least within the same script element - see [5.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-components-intro-20130606/#lifecycle-callbacks) for example of this.

What is this construct `({ tick: ... })` called? How it works? Part of which spec is this?

---

**Clarification:** my question is  why `this.tick` is assumed to work? I cannot reproduce it to work in a browser.

---

**Edit:** as stated in [this email](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2013AprJun/0152.html) on W3C's webapps mailing list, part of the spec I was refering to is now obsolete, partly becaue of `this` -> prototype binding I was asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is this construct ({ tick: ... }) called?

An [*object initializer*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5).

> How it works?

An object initializer is made up of a series of *property initializers* (`name: value`). The value in each property initializer is evaluated and then assigned to the property. The value of your `tick` property is a function, but it could easily be a string, number, another object, whatever.

> Part of which spec is this?

The object initializer is from the ECMAScript spec (ECMAScript being the technical name for the standardized language that we all call JavaScript). The [current spec is the 5th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) but object initializers were there from the beginning.

The part taking the properties from that object initializer and adding them to the element object is from that very spec, the web components spec. See [Section 5.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-components-intro-20130606/#methods-and-properties):

> The properties of the last value of the script will be copied to a prototype object created for you. In the above example, `<tick-tock-clock>` elements will have a tick method.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. This sentence covers it: "The properties of the last value of the script will be copied to a prototype object created for you". I missed it somehow. You can delete all but last two paragraphs of your answer :)

Comment: I asked around on public-webapps@w3.org and, as it turns out, binding `this` to new elements prototype is now obsolete. See last edit in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The Web Components Custom Elements spec has indefinitely shelved the declarative `<element>` method of defining custom elements for various performance and platform feasibility reasons. Instead you should be using the imperative `document.register()` DOM API to declare your custom elements, as outlined in the up-to-date spec here: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/custom/index.html

*(**Note**: I am a participant in the working group for this family of specs - of which, implementations are scheduled to land in Chrome and Firefox around the end of 2013)*